# jQueryUI buttonsets require unique ID's

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, button, label

If you create a buttonset of radio/checkbox inputs using jQueryUI, you must use explicit labels. This means you must associate a `label` by ID to an `input`.

If you want to use multiple identical buttonsets on the same page, this means you can't just use the same code for every buttonset, because ID's must be unique in a document.

Most browsers will accept non-unique ID's, but I'd rather not be forced to break web standards, and obviously there is no guarentee that browsers will continue to support non-unique ID's in the future.

I could generate unique ID's for every situation, but that complicates code and adds the problem of guarenteeing the ID's are indeed unique.

What is the best way to deal with multiple identical buttonsets?

This demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/C3NyV/1/

In my particular situation, the buttonset is generated by a plugin created using the Widget factory. I don't know if this helps with a solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of jQuery UI you should be matching all input's `id` attributes to a label with the `for` attribute for accessibility reasons.  When a screen reader encounters an input field it looks for a matching label using this criteria.

Instead of generating a unique identifier I would recommend using something more semantic to differentiate between the different sets.  It may be more work but it'll be more standard, accessible, and maintainable code.

Comment: Well, I'd like to, but the problem is this: 1. jQueryUI buttonset() requires the use of ID's. 2. HTML spec requires ID's to be unique. These two seem to be at odds with eachother if you want to use a buttonset multiple times on a single page. Differentiating between the sets isn't part of the problem as I reference the DOM nodes directly.

Comment: Could you be specific about which 2 ids are required?  I updated your Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bRhRM/1/, the only ids that are different between the two containers are the ids on the 4 radio buttons themselves, which are necessary for accessible markup anyways.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the HTML code for the radiobuttons would be generated client-side, which makes creating unique ID's difficult. No guarentees the generated ID doesn't already exist unless you do a relatively expensive generate/check-if-exists loop. Ideally buttonset() would not rely on ID's.

Comment: I would agree that having radio inputs within a label should just work; there's a jQuery UI bug documentation this - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6063.  I don't believe that generating a unique identifier would be very expensive.  Messy code, yes, but it wouldn't be expensive unless you had a ton of these things on the DOM.